# python + replace number in file using subprocess.call & sed

Tags: linux, sed, python

We have python version - 2.7.5 on my Linux machine - redhat 7.3

I write this simple script in order to use sed to replace string in file

```
more  test.py
#!/usr/bin/env python


import subprocess
subprocess.call("sed s'/2.6/2.6.4/g' /tmp/file.xml")
```

but we got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
    subprocess.call("sed s'/2.6/2.6.4/g' /tmp/file.xml")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

what is wrong with the python script ?

```
 more file.xml

 2.6.0.3-8
```

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Comment: also, why not do it with python itself? assuming you want inplace editing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453267/is-it-possible-to-modify-lines-in-a-file-in-place

Comment: and note that `2.6` will match `2a6` , `276` etc... use `2\.6` instead

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

when using

- [`subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.call) 
  or
- [`subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize=0, executable=None, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, preexec_fn=None, close_fds=False, shell=False, cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=False, startupinfo=None, creationflags=0)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen)

> `args` is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
>   of program arguments. **Providing a sequence of arguments is generally
>   preferred**, as it allows the module to take care of any required
>   escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
>   names). If passing a single string, either `shell` must be `True` (see
>   below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed
>   without specifying any arguments.
>   
> ...
>   If `shell` is `True`, the specified command will be executed through
>   the shell. This can be useful if you are using Python primarily for
>   the enhanced control flow it offers over most system shells and still
>   want convenient access to other shell features such as shell pipes,
>   filename wildcards, environment variable expansion, and expansion of
>   `~` to a user’s home directory.

So, your approach will work when specifying:

```
subprocess.call("sed s'/2\.6/2.6.4/g' /tmp/file.xml", shell=True)
```

But ...

> **Warning**: Using `shell=True` can be a security hazard.
>   Executing shell commands that incorporate unsanitized input from an
>   untrusted source makes a program vulnerable to *shell injection*, a
>   serious security flaw which can result in arbitrary command execution.
>   For this reason, the use of `shell=True` is **strongly discouraged**
>   in cases where the command string is constructed from external input.
>
> When using `shell=True`, `pipes.quote()` can be used to properly
>   escape whitespace and shell metacharacters in strings that are going
>   to be used to construct shell commands.

Conclusion: when passing `args` (i.e. command) as a single string (with `shell=True` being set) you should at least escape/quote it.
But, as mentioned above, providing a sequence of arguments is highly preferred:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['sed', 's/2\.6/2.6.4/g', '/tmp/file.xml'])
```